# MS Access VBA DoCmd.OpenForm WhereCondition failing with field not found error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using VBA to open a form. The form has a Crosstab query for the recordsource, if that matters.
I am trying

```
DoCmd.OpenForm Form_frmMyForm.Name, , , "ID = 7"
```

(eventually I will replace the "= 7" with something more useful. This is just for testing)

But I get an error when it gets to that line:

```
Run-time error '3070":
The Microsoft Access database engine does not recognize 'ID' as a valid field name or expression.
```

I have positively confirmed that the field 'ID' is in my crosstab query. In fact, I use that field in several controls without issue.

I also tried

```
 Form_frmMyForm.Recordset.FindFirst "ID = 7"
 MsgBox (Form_frmMyForm.Recordset.NoMatch)
```

and it shows "False", indicating that there was a match, however, the form does not advance to that record.

Any ideas what I may be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
Form_frmMyForm.Recordset.FindFirst "ID = 7"
```

to

```
Form_frmMyForm.Recordset.FindFirst "[ID] = 7"
```

You need those square brackets when referencing a field from a recordset.  Then to use a variable you can do:

```
Form_frmMyForm.Recordset.FindFirst ("[ID] = " & Me.Whatever & "")
```

UPDATE:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm Form_frmMyForm.Name, , , Form_frmMyForm.Recordset.FindFirst "[ID] = 7"
```

Comment: This seems to work with the findfirst method thanks. I will mark as answered. However, it does not work with the doCmd.OpenForm method. Any ideas why? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is ID in the underlying data or a column that is generated by the cross-tab?

I wonder if the condition is applied before the cross tab columns are generated, so that when it starts to get the data (and tries to apply the condition) it can't see the ID column because it's not yet been created.

Comment: It is underlying data. In fact, the fieldname is more like table1.id. I thought I had tried every combination of square brackets as @TKEyi60 suggested below, but what finally worked (in the findfirst method) was [table1].ID = 7. But it does not work in the DoCmd.OpenForm wherecondition. I just get an error that the field is not found.

Comment: try moving it from the Where argument to the Filter one (I thing that is the argument immediately before)